# Laravel Passport: Target [Lcobucci\JWT\Parser] is not instantiable while building [Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenFactory]

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

It's my first time trying out this package and I followed the installation guide at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport but when this code block in my controller signup action it throws the error:

```
$token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
```

Here's the code for my signup action:

```
public function signup(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|string|email:rfc,dns|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    $user->save();

    $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!',
        'access_token' => $token
    ], 201);
}
```

- Passport Version: 10.0
- Laravel Version: 8.16.1
- PHP Version: 7.4.13
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7.24

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found the solution on: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1381.

In composer.json just add "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3" and execute composer update.

Comment: I get this error

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[3.3.3].
    - lcobucci/jwt 3.3.3 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev] require lcobucci/jwt ^3.4|^4.0 -> found lcobucci/jwt[3.4.0, ..., 3.4.x-dev, 4.0.0-alpha1, ..., 4.2.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (3.3.3).
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^10.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., 10.x-dev].

Comment: this solution only works for PHP 7, whereas PHP 8 is enforced since Laravel 9

Answer (score 9):

```sh
## Works in Laravel 7
composer require lcobucci/jwt:"^3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same environment and adding "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3" package and update composer fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i got this issue when i execute the
`composer update`
command.
after a bit of searching i figure it found and downgraded my composer.lock file again to its old versions by

```
git restore composer.lock
```

then executed the

```
composer install
```

for installing the packges again